# mysql error 1193 (HY00): Uknown System variable 'loopCnt'

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

heres the code from @Shaharsh Shah:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ trig_auto_spid$$

CREATE
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
TRIGGER `trig_auto_spid` AFTER INSERT ON `tapes` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT REPLACE(TSpecID, 'TS', '') INTO @counter 
    FROM Tape_Specific_ID 
    ORDER BY TSpecID DESC LIMIT 1;

    SET loopCnt = @counter + new.qty; 
    WHILE (@counter <= loopCnt) DO 
        INSERT INTO Tape_Specific_ID(TapesID, TSpecID) 
        VALUES (new.TapesID, CONCAT('TS', @counter)); 
        SET @counter:=@counter + 1;
    END WHILE; 
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

when creating this trigger an error occured errorr 1193 (HY00):Uknown System variable 'loopCnt', why?any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it a `user variable`

```
SET @loopCnt := @counter + new.qty; 
WHILE (@counter <= @loopCnt) DO
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SET @counter := 10;
SET @loopCnt := @counter + new.qty; 
WHILE (@counter <= @loopCnt) DO
```

Comment: in addition, hw cn i set the initial value of @counter=10?

Comment: @NeilBryanCasinang before the `SET @loopCnt..`, add this line `SET @counter := 10`

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
SET @loopCnt = @counter + new.qty; 
WHILE (@counter <= @loopCnt) DO
```

User defined variables need a `@` in front, otherwise it thinks it's a variable from system, which is nowhere defined.

Comment: in addition, hw cn i set the initial value of @counter=10?